# Какое наклонение у глаголов в репликах "Проходим!", "Не задержимаемся!" и т.д

Tags: глаголы

Довольно часто в разговорной речи я слышу, что в побудительных фразах используются глаголы множественного числа первого лица настоящего времени.

Например, контроллер в автобусе: *"Садимся, не задерживаем рейс"*.

На приеме окулиста: *"Смотрим на первую строчку. Читаем буквы вслух"*.

И т.д.

В книжках по грамматике описания этого явления не нашел. К какому наклонению следует относить эти глаголы к повелительному или изъявительному?

Answer (score 6):

Так называемый "[инклюзивный](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2) [императив](http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/imperativ-v-raznostrukturnyh-yazykah-v-kontrastivno-tipologicheskom-plane)", ещё одно наследие финно-угорских языков.
Возможно и франкофонное влияние, но версия с инклюзивным императивом лично мне представляется более достоверной, т. к. в кругах, где используется такая форма, вряд ли ценится наследие именно франкофонной традиции.

Может быть и собственно славянским явлением (по крайней мере, инклюзивный императив как самостоятельная категория [выделяется в балканских языках](http://vetarsabalkana.com/d/513918/d/bosniyskiy-horvatskiy-serbskiy---grammatika-s-sociolingvisticheskimi-kommentariyami.pdf) - см. стр. 119), но в этом случае вновь встаёт вопрос славянской прародины.

Поскольку в русской культуре важен статус в коммуникации, а в разговорной речи повелительное обращение может рассматриваться как форма речевой агрессии, то "инклюзивный императив" - это своеобразная форма вежливого обращения. Впрочем, именно меня такая форма обращения обычно выбешивает.

Таким образом, это повелительное наклонение (императив).

Comment: Спасибо, это многое объясняет. Насчет франкофонной версии, тоже вполне возможно, т.к. такое явление оч. распространенно в университетах и всяких канцелярских учреждениях.

Comment: Повелительное наклонение первого лица множественного числа есть и в финском, и во французском. Разделение на инклюзивные-эксклюзивные формы в финском довольно условно и главным образом сводится к различию между старыми и новыми формами (новая совпадает с так называемым "четвёртым лицом"). Во французском обе формы, насколько я помню, не различаются.

Comment: Manjusri: Ухожу в оффтоп, но... В чём может заключаться франкофонное влияние?  On y va = Идём; On y voit = Смотрим.  Французы, подразумевая инклюзивность, используют глагол в ед. ч. 3-м л., а русские используют глагол во мн. ч. 1-м л.

Comment: Revenons à nos moutons.

Comment: +1 за "Revenons...".  Дополнительно, повелительное наклонение с использованием глаголов 1-го лица, множественного числа широко распространено в украинском (працюємо, чекаємо) и белорусском (працуем, чакаем) языках.

Answer (score 4):

Это одна из форм [повелительного наклонения](http://www.bibliotekar.ru/russkiy-yazik-2/170.htm). У него [много вариантов есть](http://uchim.org/russkij-yazyk/naklonenie-glagola):

> «стоять!» (= инфинитиву)
>
> «встали!» (= прошедшему времени)
>
> «пойдём!», «пойдёмте!» (= формам
> будущего времени 1-го лица мн. ч.)
>
> «да здравствует!» (= настоящему времени 3-го лица ед. ч.)
>
> «помог бы ты мне!» (= форме условного наклонения)
>
> «награди тебя Бог!» (обращение формой 2-го лица к 3-му лицу)
>
> и т. д.

Comment: Из вашей ссылки больше подходит на то что описано в http://www.bibliotekar.ru/russkiy-yazik-2/172.htm
Но там почему-то речь только о будущем времени. У меня в примере настоящее, т.к. будущее это "пройдем", "не задержимся", "рассмотрим", "присядем" и т.д.

Comment: @DenisKreshikhin - Вы же видите. сколько там вариантов, всех не перечислишь. Побуждение к действию – это повелительное наклонение, как бы оно не выражалось, а в ваших примерах именно побуждение к действию.

Comment: @DenisKreshikhin - «Идём со мной!» – что это, не повелительное наклонение, скажете? Но по форме это совпадает с настоящим, 1 л. мн. ч., как у вас.

Comment: ну если по вашим ссылкам, то по форме это  изъявительное наклонение в значении повелительного.

Comment: @DenisKreshikhin - Именно об этом я в своём ответе и написал.

Comment: Нет, вы написали что это одна из форм повелительного. Хотя по форме это изъявительное наклонение.

Comment: @DenisKreshikhin - Понимаете, знать значение написанных слов и уметь читать – это разные вещи. Вы что, сами не видели, что ваши примеры по форме это изъявительное наклонение? Если видели, то зачем было задавать вопрос? Или вы не знали значения повелительного наклонения? Я вам объяснил в ответе, что _некоторые формы повелительного наклонения могут по форме совпадать с формами других наклонений, в т. ч. и изъявительного_. Вы что, там знаки «равно» не видели? Или формулировка _«изъявительное наклонение в значении повелительного_ радикально меняет всю суть?

Comment: Мне интересно получить аргументированный ответ. Спасибо конечно за ссылки, это позновательно. Но полноценного ответа я от вас не получил.

Comment: @DenisKreshikhin - Если вы спрашиваете о наклонениях, то это подразумеват, что вы знаете, какие они есть и что каждое из них в целом означает. Ваш ворпрос настолько банален, что ответ на него ни в какой особой аргументации не нуждается, он самоочевиден. Аргументированый ответ звучал бы так: вы же видите, что по форме это изъявительное наклонение? Да. Но передают ли эти предложения реальную ситуацию? Нет. Это побуждения к действию. А какое наклонение такое значение имеет? Повелительное. Значит это и есть повелительное наклонение. То есть, просто по определению.